How to pass C# object as parameter to Oracle db using dapper (.NET8)
In .NET version 4.8, we added an object and executed the procedure like this:
  List<OracleParameter> parameters = new List<OracleParameter>();
OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter
{
    ParameterName = "P_HA_RECORD",
    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
    UdtTypeName = "STX.VM_OBJECT_TYPE", // Note: The UdtTypeName is case-sensitive
    Value = Type
};
parameters.Add(parameter);

Now I am adding it like this in .NET 8, but it doesn't work as expected. I should mention that Type is an object, and for each property within it, the following is specified, for example:
[OracleObjectMapping("CLIENT_L_NAME")]
public string ClientLName 

adding parameter
  var parameters = new OracleDynamicParameters();
OracleParameter udtParameter = new OracleParameter("P_HA_RECORD", OracleDbType.Object)
{
    UdtTypeName = "STX.VM_OBJECT_TYPE",
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
    Value = Type
};

parameters.Add("P_HA_RECORD", udtParameter);

